# how does apache Name-based virtual host work

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

As apache doc said:

```
 The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
 match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
```

How to understand this sentence?

If my configuration like this(assume that hostname `test.com` is valid):

```
<VirtualHost *>
   DocumentRoot "/www/test"
   ServerName a.test.com
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit `b.test.com`, apache will use The first VirtualHost section,But it could not resolve host.

Comment: To use those hostnames you should have DNS resolv for them

Comment: Thanks, But if hostname in the example is valid, How does apache Name-based virtual host work?

Comment: What is not clear in to the doc you quote?

Comment: Thanks again, I think I get it.